# Media screen queries shown on inspect but not on actual device

Tags: css, media-queries

I've tried googling and can't seem to get this right.

I've made the media screen query codes & viewport for iPhone 7 plus but it just won't appear on my device. I've tried inspecting on Chrome and it appears as it should. This is the code:

```
@media screen and (height:736px) and (width:414px){
  div.banner{
  height:600px;
  background-image:url(../../assets/img/mobilehome.jpg)!important
}
```

Comment: 1. It's not related with PHP - change tags. 2. Can you provide SO Snippet? Now you have syntax error in your CSS

Comment: `@media screen and (height:736px) , screen and (width:414px) {
  div.banner{
  height:600px;
  background-image:url(../../assets/img/mobilehome.jpg)!important;
}
}`

This must be the proper format of css. Don't use important, use max/min height and width.

Comment: In the code above, you're missing a } in the end. Dunno if its messing something else.

Comment: Sorry I didnt paste the code fully. This is the snippet https://jsfiddle.net/teddbundy/t1yn84w0/8/ (removed the previous since I kinda use the same picture so ppl wont be able to tell the difference)

Answer (score -1):

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}
```

Credits: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Better mention the another answer of stackoverflow link. Also the op has height for specific reasons.

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) work, a good answer should always contain an explanation of what the code does and how it solves the question.

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer with the source credits. Concerning the explanation, if one would really target one device, using css media queries isn't just enough, however these devices work in this range (and probably a dozen more out there). I realized the height issue, so I'm testing for a max-height rule but this will probably get the op into trouble. So I guess javascript will probably be the way to go.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I've tried this code but it doesnt work.  Code appears in Inspect element but when I try to view on actual device, the picture stays the same. This screenshot shows that the code actually works in inspect https://imgur.com/a/R05gboM & this is my snippet https://jsfiddle.net/teddbundy/90jebfut/.